# Angular Material Vertical Stepper | Extend vertical line in last step

Tags: angular, angular-material, stepper, mat-stepper

Is it possible to extend the `vertical line` in the last step?

The template script prevents it:

```
<div class="mat-vertical-content-container" [class.mat-stepper-vertical-line]="!isLast">
```

This is what it is now in the last step:
[image: Current]

This is desired:
[image: Desired]

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css:

```
::ng-deep .mat-step:last-child .mat-vertical-content-container {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
}
```